# Changing enum state in script 1 by changing dropdown value in script 2. "Are you missing assembly reference?"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The the error I'm getting is "Are you missing assembly reference?"

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class DropdownControllers : MonoBehaviour {

//Dropdown objects in hierarch, these variables are checked in the switch 
cases in update function
public Dropdown mapType, locations;

// Handle to GoogleAPI script which has the google maps code with MapType 
and Locations enums.
public GoogleAPI _mapSelected, _locationSelected;

// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{
    //Calls populateDropDown function which populates the dropdown
    PopulateDropDowns();



    //Gets enums from GoogleAPI script
    _locationSelected.GetComponent<GoogleAPI>();
    _mapSelected.GetComponent<GoogleAPI>();
}

//Populates dropdowns with options
public void PopulateDropDowns()
{
    //Changes the caption text
    locations.GetComponent<Dropdown>().captionText.text = "Location";
    mapType.GetComponent<Dropdown>().captionText.text = "Map type";

    List<string> locationNames = new List<string>
    {
        "Pentraeth Forest", //0
        "Newborough Forest", //1
        "Other Forest" //2
    };

    //take the list of strings and add them to locations dropdown
    locations.GetComponent<Dropdown>().AddOptions(locationNames);

    //Same as above but for Maptype.
    List<string> mapTypeNames = new List<string>
    {
        "Roadmap", //0
        "Satellite", //1
        "Hybrid", //2
        "Terrain" //3
    };

    mapType.GetComponent<Dropdown>().AddOptions(mapTypeNames);
}


// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{

    //Switch case to check the value in dropdown. 
    switch (locations.value)
    {
        case 0:
            Debug.Log("Pentraeth");

            //if value of dropdown is 0, change the state of locations enum 
           within the Google API to Pentraeth. 
            try {
                _locationSelected.locationSelected = 
                GoogleAPI.Locations.Pentraeth;
                Debug.Log("Enum changed to Pentraeth");                }
            catch
            {
                Debug.Log(" Error, Enum cannot be changed to Pentraeth");
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            Debug.Log("Newbough");
            try
            {
                _locationSelected.locationSelected = 
                GoogleAPI.Locations.Newborough;
                Debug.Log("Enum changed to Newborough");
            }
            catch
            {
                Debug.Log(" Error, Enum cannot be changed to Newborough");
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            Debug.Log("Another");
            try
            {
                _locationSelected.locationSelected = 
                GoogleAPI.Locations.Another;
                Debug.Log("Enum changed to Another");
            }
            catch
            {
                Debug.Log(" Error, Enum cannot be changed to Another");
            }
            break;


    }
}


}
```

I've got a dropdowncontroller object with the dropdown script within it, then i've dragged the two dropdown objects into the script.

The GoogleAPi script that has the enums is in a rawimage object which is the map. There is no reference to the dropdowns within the GoogleAPI script. Only the enums. Should there be?

The "Missing assembly reference error is for the 3 "_locationSelected.locationSelected = GoogleAPI.Locations.Pentraeth;" 
"_locationSelected.locationSelected = GoogleAPI.Locations.Newborough;" 
"_locationSelected.locationSelected = GoogleAPI.Locations.Another;"

The idea will be to have 2 switch cases. 1 to check Locationsdropdown value, then change the state of the Locations enum which has the variable locationSelected and then change the lat and lon coordinates, then generate a new map.

The other switch case should do exactly the same logic but change the maptype rather than lat and lon.

I've put the switch case in try, catch so I can get some debug.logs, is that correct?

Think I've been clear enough!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. Guess it's a bug because Unity and Visual Studio just needed a restart. Now the error has gone.

So if anyone gets 'Error CS1061: Are you missing an assembly reference?' And everything looks OK. Just restart. Worked for me, I've seen another thread in which it worked for them too.

Answer (score 1):

The error seems pretty clear. You need to add a using statement at the top of your document referencing the googleapi.

Comment: Do you mean like 'using GoogleAPI;' The GoogleAPI being the script name and that goes at the top of Dropdown script?